# Disk defrag won't start

Tags: windows-7

I have a problem, the disk defragger wont show up when I try to run it. I did some research on google and concluded it had to do with the services. So, what is the name of the service needed for dfrgui.exe ? I'm using windows 7 home premium 64-bit

Answer (score 1):

NET START will not work on disabled services, so make sure it is enabled: go to Control panel, Services. Make sure "Disk Defragmenter" start type is set to Manual.

Or run:

> sc config defragsvc start= demand

Comment: I'll try as soon as I get home.

Answer (score 0):

"Disk defragmenter", as in

```
NET START disk defragmenter
```

Note that doesn't start a defrag, just starts the service.

Comment: And when I've started the service, I'm able to start disk defragger?

Comment: Should be able to do so.  However, the task scheduler also has to be running (even if you are manually starting the defragger.)